# How can create range index on element which has multiple namespace

Tags: xquery, marklogic, marklogic-8

We have different type of documents in Marklogic database. All document contain element **"title"** which has different type of namespace. I want to create a facet on all **"title"** elements which is available in the all documents. So we are trying to create range index on element **"title"** but how provide all namespaces in namespace uri field. Any suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

I think the most straight-forward way is to create a [field](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/fields) on those elements (or paths), and then add a field range index.

HTH!

Comment: I agree with @grtjn -- a field is the way to go. To help, here's the relevant section of the docs: http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/fields.